# Задание, реализовать функцию

Tags: python

**Реализуйте функцию     solve( ), которая на вход получает два аргумента:**

- строку str_obj,
- число i

Аргумент **i** должен иметь значение по умолчанию равное 2 (двум).

**Функция должна:**

1. продублировать входную строку i раз,
2. сформировать новую строку из продублированной строки: выбрать каждый
   i-й символ с конца продублированной строки
3. вернуть новую строку.

Для не положительных i функция должна вернуть исходную строку.

---

Input: MwryrLZrOxVTTLOv 5
Result: vVLMTZwTrrLOyOxr

​

Comment: и как вы пытались ее решить?

Comment: Отличное задание. Делайте.

Comment: Вы похоже немного заблудились, это не фриланс, сдесь за вас никто ничего делать не будет, вам лишь немного помогут

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. чтобы продублировать строку `count` раз в питоне можно строку умножить на `count`:

   ```
    text_new = text_old * count
   ```
2. чтобы сформулировать новую строку взяв каждый `step` символ можно разными способами

способ 1 (через срезы) - самый простой

```
text_new = text_old[::step]
```

способ 2 (через цикл)

```
arr = [text[pos] for pos in range(0, len(text), step)]
```

способ 3 (через цикл)

```
arr = [obj[1] for obj in enumerate(text) if obj[0] % step == 0]
```

дерзайте дальше сами

Comment: кто минусов накидал ? объясните чтоли за что.

Comment: @Интик за решение домашек за автора?